# Batch variable GEQ x and if LSS y then output z

Tags: batch-file

I have the below batch code which takes a value as input, determines if it is in a specific range, and then should set a new variable and output it.  However, it does not work as expected.  First, the code:

```
set /p wndBr=<C:\summaries\daily_values_wind_bearing.txt
if %wndBr% GEQ 56.25 if %wndBr% LSS 78.75 set wndDir="ENE"
if %wndBr% GEQ 78.75 if %wndBr% LSS 101.25 set wndDir="E"
if %wndBr% GEQ 101.25 if %wndBr% LSS 123.75 set wndDir="ESE"
echo %wndBr%
echo %wndDir%
```

When I run this, I get:

```
C:\summaries>set /p wndBr= 0<C:\summaries\daily_values_wind_bearing.txt
C:\summaries>if 89.68 GEQ 56.25 if 89.68 LSS 78.75 set wndDir="ENE"
C:\summaries>if 89.68 GEQ 78.75 if 89.68 LSS 101.25 set wndDir="E"
C:\summaries>if 89.68 GEQ 101.25 if 89.68 LSS 123.75 set wndDir="ESE"
C:\summaries>echo 89.68
89.68
C:\summaries>echo
ECHO is on.
```

As shown, the input variable, `wndBr`, happens to be 89.68, so the middle if statement should be used.  I've tested and it doesn't appear that the if logic is incorrect.  The issue appears to be setting the `wndDir` variable.  I've tried parenthesis around the statement, quotes around the value, no quotes, %% around the variable, using `set /p`, ect.  Clearly I am missing something, but not sure what else to test.

For reference, this code is supposed to take the average wind bearing (from 0 to 360 degrees) and then convert it to direction, IE the example above.  For more "fun", I still have yet to figure out how to determining how to get "North" (`if "%wndBr%" GEQ 0.00 if LSS 11.25 OR GEQ 348.75 if LSS 0.00 goto set wndDir="N"`  <-- I know using OR is wrong, I just haven't attempted to fix it yet until I can get the "easier" ones working).

Comment: `cmd` doesn't support floating point numbers. So `if 89.68 LSS 101.25` is STRING comparison, which makes `89.68 actually "bigger" than `101.25`. I'd like to see the exact output of `echo "%wndBr%" after the `set /p` command too.

Comment: Does the number from the file always have two digits after the dot? Then just removing the dot converts to an integer (`set "wndBr=%wndBr:.=%"`), which should be sufficient to correct your logic.

Comment: Hey @Stephan, it outputs 89.68 exactly.  And for you and @Mofi, the input from the txt file (which in this example is 89.68) doesn't have to be that precise.  The value written into the db each minute during the day is just an integer, 0-359.  So, I can adjust mysql from `select format(avg(Windbearing),2) from `monthly_new` where LogDateTime between current_date - interval 1 day and current_date;` to `..format(avg(Windbearing),0)..`

Comment: Also, sorry for the above comment.  It removed some of the code sample markings..

Comment: @sbagnato: You wrote: _"The value written into the db each minute during the day is just an integer, 0-359"_. Then, why you write it to the text file with two decimal digits? Just to complicate things? **`:(`**

Comment: @Aacini, I like to make things tough :)  Not really, honestly it was due to oversight.  Many of the other values, such as various temperatures and rain-related values, are using two digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this may help you. It only works with integer degrees:

```
@echo off
setlocal

:loop
set "wndBr="
set /P "wndBr=Enter wind bearing: "
if not defined wndBr goto :EOF

for %%a in (0:N  11:NNE  34:NE  56:ENE  79:E
                101:ESE 124:SE 146:SSE 169:S
                191:SSW 214:SW 236:WSW 259:W
                281:WNW 304:NW 326:NNW 349:N ) do (
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%b in ("%%a") do if %wndBr% geq %%b set "wndDir=%%c"
)

echo %wndBr% = %wndDir%

goto loop
```

However, if the input value have two decimal digits, just convert it to integer via `for /F "delims=." %%a in ("%wndBr%) do set "wndBr=%%a"`

**EDIT**: *Output example added*

```
Enter wind bearing: 40
40 = NE
```

**EDIT**: *Code modified*

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /p wndBr=<C:\summaries\daily_values_wind_bearing.txt

for %%a in (0:N  11:NNE  34:NE  56:ENE  79:E
                101:ESE 124:SE 146:SSE 169:S
                191:SSW 214:SW 236:WSW 259:W
                281:WNW 304:NW 326:NNW 349:N ) do (
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%b in ("%%a") do if %wndBr% geq %%b set "wndDir=%%c"
)

echo %wndBr% = %wndDir%
```